# How to enable DBMS_OUTPUT in SQL Developer?

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

[output for below code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha2yU.png)

```
DECLARE

a int;

b int;

c int;

BEGIN

a:=&a;

b:=&b;

c:=a+b;

dbms_output.put_line('Sum of a and b is '||c);

end;

/
```

Comment: did you forget to ´SET SERVEROUTPUT ON´?

Comment: If the issue is output, you can test it with `dbms_output.put_line('Hello');` and skip all the arithmetic stuff. Are you actually using [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/) or did you just tag it because the question is about development in PL/SQL?

Comment: From the screenshot it seems you are using SQL Developer, which has a slightly complicated way of displaying dbms_output. First you have to show the dbms_output pane using View > DBMS_OUTPUT. Then you have to enable it by pressing the green "+" symbol in the dbms_output pane.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson. I am just a new developer new to PL/SQL platform. While learning I got this issue.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 6):

In SQL Developer you have to

1. Show the DBMS_OUTPUT pane using View > DBMS_OUTPUT.

[image]

2. Enable it by pressing the green "+" symbol in the output pane.

[image]

Comment: You don't have to, you can also just set serveroutput on

Comment: Hi Jeff, do you have a link to a definitive how-to guide for enabling DBMS_OUTPUT in SQL Developer? Happy to edit the above.

Comment: Actually maybe it's https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/05/enabling-dbms_output-by-default-in-sql-developer/

Comment: Yes, that's it.