# PLSQL procedure is successfully completed but there is no output

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
 set serveroutput on; 
 declare v_test VARCHAR2(30); 
 begin 
    v_test := 'NAMASTE'; 
    dbms_output.put_line('Hello PlSQL');
    dbms_output.put_line(v_test);
    
 end; /
```

Comment: Where is your procedure? This by itself works just ok: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=30135860141a62c0a8891e9a6a0387e4

Comment: Your code works [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2f998948095584156c64083ef1d92484)

Comment: That gives the expected output in SQL\*Plus and SQL Developer - the two lines of output you request, followed by the 'PL/SQL procedure successfully completed' message. If you are using SQL Developer, did you perhaps use 'run statement' (clicking the green arrow icon, or control-enter) rather than 'run script' (clicking the document+green arrow icon, or F5) - so it didn't execute the `set` command and just ran the PL/SQL block? That would explain what you're seeing. Otherwise, which client/IDE are you using, and how are you running the code?

Comment: I am using sql developer 18.2 version...including jdk... so pls tell me whch editor i should use...because the above code runs on oracle 10g ...but not on sql developer.

Comment: Again, it does work in SQL Developer, if you execute both statements. (You can also enable the separate 'Dbms Output' panel from the View menu, and connect from there too; then you don't need the `serveroutput` setting.)

Comment: To enable output in SQL Developer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70146599/230471

Comment: dbms_output will not work with system account in SQLDeveloper. Check which account you are using.